# subprograms and methods

Tags: java, methods

trying to follow the instructions within the comments but I've been at it for hours and think I need help from someone with a bit more experience. basically I am looking to receive values from the user for a and b and these will be passed on to a section of code which works out the magnitude which will then be passed onto a section of code which displays the magnitude, Code can be seen below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Software Development 1, Lab 3 Task 1: Write a program to calculate the
 * magnitude of a 2D vector The magnitude calculation should take place in a
 * separate method.
 */
public class OneVector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readComponents();
        double magnitude = calculateMagnitude(a);
        displayMag(magnitude);
    }

    // TODO: Read in the two components from the user
    public static double readComponents() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter a value for vector 1");
        double a = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("enter a value for vector 2");
        double b = scan.nextDouble();
        return (a);
        return (b);

    }

    // TODO: Use the calculateMagnitude method to find its magnitude
    static void calculateMag() {

    }

    // TODO: Display the vector's magnitude to the user
    public static void displayMag(double magnitude) {
        System.out.println(magnitude);

    }

    /*
     * Calculates the magnitude of a 2D vector.
     */
    public static double calculateMagnitude(double a, double b) {
        // TODO: Write code to calculate the vector's magnitude
        double magnitude = Math.sqrt((a * a) + (b * b));

        // TODO: Return the calculated magnitude to the main method
        return magnitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: You try to return two values from `readComponents()` and there are existing questions on Stack Overflow for that, so you can look them up. But does this method even need to return two values? Wouldn't it be much easier for you to just return one value and call this method twice, instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given below is the corrected answer:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Software Development 1, Lab 3 Task 1: Write a program to calculate the
 * magnitude of a 2D vector The magnitude calculation should take place in a
 * separate method.
 */
public class OneVector {
    static double a,b;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readComponents();
        double magnitude = calculateMagnitude(a,b);
        displayMag(magnitude);
    }

    // TODO: Read in the two components from the user
    public static void readComponents() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter a value for vector 1");
        a = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("enter a value for vector 2");
        b = scan.nextDouble();
    }

    // TODO: Use the calculateMagnitude method to find its magnitude
    static void calculateMag() {

    }

    // TODO: Display the vector's magnitude to the user
    public static void displayMag(double magnitude) {
        System.out.println(magnitude);

    }

    /*
     * Calculates the magnitude of a 2D vector.
     */
    public static double calculateMagnitude(double a, double b) {
        // TODO: Write code to calculate the vector's magnitude
        double magnitude = Math.sqrt((a * a) + (b * b));

        // TODO: Return the calculated magnitude to the main method
        return magnitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

the send return statement in

```
 readComponents()
```

will never get executed and for basic concepts you can refer to a book:

```
Head First Java
```